# Generate JSX for rendering outside component

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm extremely new to `React`, infact I'm on lecture 23 out of 247 for udemy and learning about states and events. I am having trouble finding an answer to this question.

We have decided at our company to use react and thus far its proving to be very good. I'm hesitant to ask this question because we haven't gotten thus far yet but it is a business requirement that we have extenral JSX since we have AUTHENTICATON logic that needs to occur and if it cannot be achieved then we are wasting our time.

My question is, is it possible to **obtain the JSX externally from an API and render it inside the Component.**

For example,

// external API returns JSX through AJAX Request

```
<div id="app">
  <SomeComponent/>
  <SomeComponent/>
  <SomeComponent/>
</div>
```

// react component

```
class Baz extends Component {
   render(){
      // fetch JSX from external source through AJAX Request
   }
}
```

What I'd really like to see is an implementation using AJAX and render method from class component.

Comment: AFAIK, from a design point of view, how react works and what it does with JSX, it doesn't make sense to have JSX from an external source. That's because JSX is just some syntactic sugar on top of React to make writing it more pleasant. So, in theory you could do without using it. In fact all the JSX is compiled during build time and then pushed to production so I don't see how getting dynamic JSX could be of any help. Disclaimer: I'm new to React myself so don't take my advice very serious :-)

Comment: We have business logic on the backend that needs to occur so we need to do external JSX

Comment: if it's not via API, but locally, you could use react code splitting, https://itnext.io/react-loading-components-dynamically-a9d8549844c4. I don't know how to do it with async api call.

Comment: You can't send React over AJax, but what you could do is load the scripts with the business logic in.

Comment: I'm thinking about the react server rendering, I think maybe we asked the wrong question. The final rendered HTML is something more solid, since JSX is more like a unfinished product if you just want to inject after fetched.

Comment: @Keith Youre telling me i cant fetch JSX over ajax and render it inside a component?

Comment: @jkushner  Yes, unless your needs are really simple.  eg. -> https://github.com/pravdomil/react-serialize  But even using that package you could only use native types,.  If you had a custom React component it will fail big time as JSON cannot serialise functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot and should not try to pass a JSX representation of your UI through the wire. The reason is simple, JSX is not a `data` format but a superset of Javascript transpiled to JS before being evaluated. What this means is that to do this you would be passing JS and then eval it. What you *could* do is pass serialized entities through the network and then display them on the client using a `React.Component` built for a specific entity. There are no standardized way to do this in JS (JSON is only a partial representation of JS objects).

Supposing you have some kind of machinery that can output "JSX", what would it
output really and how would it materialize in your code

Supposing there is a `Page` component rendering this like :

```
const Page = (JSX) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {JSX}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Where JSX is the **value** you obtained through your API and this value is as
your example:

```
<div id="app">
  <SomeComponent/>
  <SomeComponent/>
  <SomeComponent/>
</div>
```

This "JSX" is transpiled to calls to `React.createElement(type, props)`
so this is actually JS objects. Those objects to be built need access to the
value of `type` which can be a `string` in the case of regular `div` element
but will most likely be classes or functions in the case of arbitrarily
generated components (`SomeComponent`). So then your rendering logic needs
to have access to those classes or functions, eval them and then use them as
argument for `React.createElement`. Basically you are lazy loading your
components.

React is (kind of) built around the idea of composable representation primitives
(Components) used to display data. In practice what this means is that your app
will identify some (potentially a lot) of possible representation for your data
and build them in a way that is composable (react components). Then given the
data produced by your users/apps/whatever, it will use thoses primitives and
their capabilities to make your data available to your users.

Comment: OK Well i have authentication business logic that determines what to display. How do I accomplish this then if i cannot use my business logic backend? How do i implement serialized entities?

Comment: The answer @adz5A gave is on point. You can use your authentication logic to let the UI decide whether to show something or not, you still don't need to send JSX from the backend to the front. However, you may want to read up on server-side rendering if you don't feel comfortable coming up with an architecture that is secure enough for your needs.

Comment: @ZekeDroid can you provide an example?

Comment: It's not "example" worthy given that it's an entire infrastructure change. I would finish learning React in its entirety and then take some courses on server-side rendering. There are many good ways to do what you're saying without this, but it could be the fastest way for you to do it if you don't have to the time to learn more complex UI security architectures

Comment: I second the comment above. I would only add that what you are looking for is a `data format` to pass between your client and your server. In the case of server side rendering this format is obviously HTML, for many APIs this is JSON. The difference between those and JSX is that JSX is in fact JavaScript. Are you confident in `eval`'ing pieces of procedurally generated JavaScript in an arbitrary context ?

Comment: Absolutely its 100% secure if you can assist in either me using external authentication against compiled react components or using data format jsx between client and server in the react render component that would be fantastic

Comment: @adz5A maybe i can do ajax requests using JSON and return whether its viewable component or not? i dont need to do the JSX external but the whole point was that it gets built on backend authenticaiton logic

Comment: And you absolutely cannot send this "backend logic" or bits of it to render in the frontend?

Comment: @ZekeDroid Id prefer to send JSX back and forth with the client and server.

Comment: I can't give an example because that's just too broad, I really wish I could though! I think the best place to start would be for you to look at broader web app infrastructure. For example, a common pattern is to have an authentication web app for your "login" screen which then redirects you to another React app where you do secure rendering (redirecting if the cookie or token is missing/out of date). You could also have the "renderings" be insecure but the data to populate it be backend authenticated. Lots of ways!

Comment: @ZekeDroid I just need the ability to communicate with the backend server and have the backend server return JSX to the client which then renders the backend provided JSX. There has to be a way around this.

Comment: @jkushner You should not be doing that, and while it may seem like a simple strategy, the reason everyone on this thread is trying to recommend against it is that it is not the right strategy. I strongly recommend against looking for a solution to send JSX back and forth, defaulting to recommending server-side rendering but even then suggesting you consider other options.

Comment: I updated my answer to make a mention about *lazy loading components*. Basically passing JSX back and forth is like passing `code` back and forth, which is not a good strategy. If you are worried about the size of the initial js bundle, then take a look at lazy loading, if it is about reusing server side logic then look at server side rendering.

Comment: @ZekeDroid Is it possible for me to build the babel javascript inside the html? im using webpack to load react and react dom but if i can load the javascript inside html that would solve the issue

Comment: You are looking for https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html I guess. Babel can run in the browser.

Comment: @adz5A I have an idea. what if the entry point differs based on ACL Role. than i wont need to decifer acl allows

Comment: I'm not sure what ACL is but if you're speaking about having fully different html pages (or root nodes for React to render into) then yes, that is one approach at securely authenticating what to show the user based on a back end authentication schema

Comment: @ZekeDroid Thanks im going to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you can substitute jsx with html on the server side, you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML property.

You can use it like this one.

```
const Page = (html) => {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html:html}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Its usage is not recommend, because users can inject malicious code to the page this way, if you use it on user input without sanitation. But from an api response it is not really a problem I think.

Comment: It would be creating JSX not HTML

Comment: Then you canot use it. But you might consider solving your problem with plain html.

Comment: Also this will open you up to html injection attacks. Hence why the `dangerously` part of the prop :)

Comment: @ZekeDroid It will not blow in your face. It is dangerous only if you use unsanitized user input in it.

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs you're right but in this case you can't sanitize it since the goal is to send javascript to be `eval`ed